# grok{} pattern for date format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Tags: date, pattern-matching, logstash, grok

The date pattern of my log file is

```
10 Sep 2014 07:16:33
```

I have added a custom pattern in grok-patterns

```
DATE_DMMY %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH}/%{YEAR}
DATE %{DATE_US}|%{DATE_EU}|%{DATE_YMD}|%{DATE_DMMY}
DATESTAMP %{DATE} %{TIME}
```

And in my logstash.conf I am using it as follows

```
filter {

grok {
patterns_dir => "/root/mypatterns"
match => ["message", "%{DATESTAMP:LOG_DATE}"]
}

date {
match => ["LOG_DATE", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"]
}

}
```

But when I execute I am getting

```
 [0] "_grokparsefailure"
```

Kindly suggest me what is wrong here. Thanks

Comment: You can go through the `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html`. I am sure this will help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using DATESTAMP, which starts with DATE.

DATE is one of:

- DATE_US, which is 11/23/2015 or 11-23-2015 (doesn't match your input)
- DATE_EU, which is 23/11/2015 or 23.11.2015 (doesn't match your input)
- DATE_YMD, which I don't see defined anywhere
- DATE_DMMY, which is "23 11/2015" (doesn't match your input)

Make a pattern that matches your input!  Also, you rarely need one pattern that expands two 4 others like this.  Imagine what the regexp would look like that you're applying to every document that comes through.

Comment: DATE_DMMY %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} fixed the issue.Thanks.